# SFTP in Node.js uploading empty files

Tags: node.js, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I'm having an issue with a project I'm working on whereby I'm downloading files from my FTP server using a node module called sftp-ssh2-client and then trying to pass the stream back into my FTP server but into a different directory.

The code looks like this:

```
const stream = sftp.get(`path/to/file.csv.gz`).then(() => {

}).catch((err) => {

});

sftp.put(stream, 'path/to/new/file.csv.gz').then(() => {

}).catch((err) => {

})
```

However, when I dial into my FTP server to the location where the file has been PUT to, the file size is 0 and when downloaded is corrupted. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Many thanks,

G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sftp.get()` doesn't return a stream, it returns a promise that *resolves* to a stream, so your code should look something like this:

```
sftp.get('path/to/file.csv.gz').then(stream => {
  return sftp.put(stream, 'path/to/new/file.csv.gz');
}).catch(err => {
  ...
});
```

However, it seems to me that you could just use [`sftp.rename()`](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client#rename), which wouldn't require downloading and uploading the entire file:

```
sftp.rename('path/to/file.csv.gz', 'path/to/new/file.csv.gz').then(...);
```

Also, if you do want to take the download-then-upload route, make sure you read the [documentation regarding encoding](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client#get).

Comment: Hi Robert - I've implemented your solution but the files are still 0 bytes when I download them?

Comment: Which encoding would I use for a .csv.gz file? I don't know where to look in the docs

Comment: _"when downloading binary data, 'null' should be passed"_. Since GZ files are binary, encoding should be `null`

Comment: I've now done this: sftp.get('path/to/file.csv.gz', false, null).then(stream => { but it still is an empty file

Comment: Try writing the stream to a local file first: `sftp.get(...).then(stream => stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('localfile')))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185313/discussion-between-user9914176-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 1):

```
 function uploadFile(req, res) {
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {
        // debug("Uploading: " + filename);
        filename = (new Date()).getTime() + '-' + filename;

        //Path where file will be uploaded
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream(FILE_STORE + filename);

        file.pipe(fstream);

        fstream.on('close', function() {
            //   debug("Upload Finished of " + filename);
            var newFileName = FILE_STORE + filename;
            if (!fs.existsSync(newFileName)) {

                res.status(404).json({ 'message': 'file not found' })
                return;
            }
            res.status(200).json({ file: filename });
        })
    })

}
```